# Answering community wiki question

Tags: support, answers, community-wiki

According to [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/339911) to the post [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/339911):

> An answer posted to a community wiki question will also be community wiki.

What is the reason to make answer community wiki **automatically** in this case?

Answer (score 4):

The point of community wiki is to make more editing happen, and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/19/the-future-of-community-wiki/), *"The intent of community wiki in answers is to help share the burden of solving a question"*, while *"questions rarely, if ever, need community wiki"* and *"Community wiki is for that rare gem of a post that needs true community collaboration."*

So you would only make hard-to-explain questions Community wiki so people collaborate more on the answers.